# Chapter style, horizontal line

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I'd like to change the chapter name style so that it appears in this way

[image]

How can I do? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« to customize the chapter heading style accordingly.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % drop in actual document!

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\itshape}
{\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{-10pt}\filleft%
  \parbox[t]{5em}{%
    \raggedleft%
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.5ex}\newline%
    \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter%
  }%
}
{4pc}
{\normalfont\upshape\bfseries\Huge}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \blinddocument  % drop in actual document!
\end{document}
```

---

[image]